# Asp.net MVC Route Query

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, routes

I have a form like below:-

```
<% using ( Html.BeginForm("search", "home", FormMethod.Get) ) { %>

<%= Html.TextBox("location", "") %>
<input type="submit" value="Search All Jobs" />

<% } %>
```

and in global.asax i have this route

```
routes.MapRoute(
"Search", // Route name
"{controller}/{action}/{location}", // URL with parameters
new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", location = UrlParameter.Optional } );
```

now whenever i click on submit button i get the url like

http://localhost/home/search?location=karachi

but i want

http://localhost/home/search/karachi

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The url you are getting is normal, that's how according to the [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#submit-format) GET parameters are sent by browsers and there's not much you could do about it.

> With the HTTP "get" method, the form
>   data set is appended to the URI
>   specified by the action attribute
>   (with a question-mark ("?") as
>   separator) and this new URI is sent to
>   the processing agent.

Your best bet is javascript to intercept the submission of the form, canceling the default action and rewriting the url. Personally I wouldn't bother with this and leave the browsers send user input as defined in the specification.

But if you really insist on achieving this here's an example of javascript:

```
$('form').submit(function() {
    var location = encodeURIComponent($('#location').val());
    var url = '<%= Url.Action("search", "home", new { location = "_TO_REPLACE_" }) %>';
    window.location.href = url.replace('_TO_REPLACE_', location);
    return false;
});
```

Comment: @John Weldon, I am afraid that it is you that are missing the point of this question. the OP wants to have `http://localhost/home/search/karachi` as url after the submission of a form with `method="GET"`. Url routes have nothing to do with the answer, neither how the action is declared on the server.

Comment: Let me add, one more thing that I have a paging control (home made) on the Search page and it will generate the desired link correctly. As it generate http://localhost/home/search/karachi?page=2

Comment: @Zohaib, that's because the paging control uses Html.ActionLink to generate url. With HTML `<form>` this is impossible. You should use javascript and that me believe is the only way to achieve what you are looking for.

Comment: @John Weldon, show me how can I achieve this? Might be, we reach at settlement.

Comment: Right; your paging control probably doesn't use a form GET, but an ActionLink.

Comment: @John Weldon @Darin Dmitrov So, this is not possible until or unless I tweak with javascript. Thanks.

Comment: @Zohaib, this is absolutely not possible without javascript as I already stated in my answer.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov As you mentioned "Personally I wouldn't bother with this (means intercept with javascript)", what's the reason behind it?

Comment: @Zohaib, because if the user enters some special characters which are not allowed to be part of a uri path the request will fail. In addition to url encoding you will need to filter those characters but then your server won't be able to receive the correct seacrh string from the user because you have removed characters from it. That's one of the reasons why the HTML specification implemented HTML forms like this.

Answer (score 1):

you actually do not need any form here, just implement `onclick` event on submit button and append the location value with your URL and do a GET request by using this javascript code.

```
var loc = document.getElementById("location");
document.location.href = "/home/search/"+loc.value;
```

Comment: Thanks dude, javascript is the only solution.